# How to use pdf.js output to convert file and send it to the back end

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js

I have a component to send files to the back end, but I need these files to be transformed into pdf. Thinking about it, I'm using PDFJs, passing the output element to it, but I noticed that it isn't working.

follow my cod

```js
uppy.on('upload', (file) => {
    this.testePdf(file);
});

testePdf(file) {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.output(file)
    doc.save('test.pdf');
}
```

he is returning empty, where am I missing?

I can't find anything on the web and the documentation is not as complete

Comment: `output` doesn't convert its argument to pdf, it's an alias for `save` http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output. I don't think jsPDF can load arbitrary files and convert them to PDF.

Comment: This is a sloppy question. Which library do you plan to use? pdf.js or jsPDF? They are not the same!